# History of graph minor concept

Tags: graph-theory, math-history

I can't find the correct reference to the first introduction of **graph minor**. There are plenty of strong results on minors (Kuratowski theorem, well-quasi-ordering by Robertson and Seymour, ...) and good introductory textbooks (by R. Diestel, B. Bollobas and others) but I have not found who first introduced the term and why.

I am writing a PhD thesis on games on graphs and I would like to have the correct historical reference while trying to have it nice and complete.

The original motivation for the concept would be very interesting as well - was it $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ minor exclusion for planar graphs, or something even older?

Comment: This would probably be tedious, but you could look at the oldest paper you know that heavily relies on the concept of a *graph minor* and trace back through the references. By doing this you should eventually hit a really old paper that actually defines a *graph minor* as a new idea.

Comment: You'd need a *very* good library for this.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) SE site.

Comment: Perhaps, but the people actually working with the concept might know it better than historians. Also, the HSM.SE site is almost empty now and I am also unsure about this fine-grained splitting of SE sites (esp. each having their own reputation etc.).